# Переопределение методов реализуемого родительским классом интерфейса

Tags: c#, .net

Имеется класс

```
public class EntitySet<TEntity>: List<TEntity> where TEntity: Enitity
```

Как известно, класс List реализует IEnumerable. Как мне переопределить метод IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault() в классе EnititySet?

Comment: 1. Не задавайте два вопроса в одном. 2. В [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) только один метод.

Comment: "при встрече с null он его нормально съедал" - ?? не очеловечивайте .NET runtime

Comment: `s.Role?.Name`. `FirstOrDefault` - это метод расширения описанный в классе `Enumerable`

Comment: Используйте элвис-оператор `?.` вкупе с оператором объединения с null `??`

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` - расширяющий метод из `System.Linq`, если вы хотите изменить его работу, то вам нужно написать свой расширяющий метод, но дать имя этого нового метода придется отличное от `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @Bulson, не придется.

Comment: @Grundy а как тогда отличать при вызове свой метод от метода из `System.Linq`?

Answer (score 0):

Никак. 
`FirstOrDefault` — метод расширения, а методы расширения невиртуальны.*

Вы можете написать в вашем классе метод `FirstOrDefault`, но код, который использовал метод [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx), будут всё так же его использовать (из-за невиртуальности).

С другой стороны, нехорошо подменять поведение по умолчанию. Скорее всего, ваша задача решается как-то по-другому.

---

*Хотя предложение о введении виртуальных методов расширения [есть](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1061).

Comment: А если написать ещё один метод расширения, но более специфичный (с параметром `this EntitySet<T>`) - он будет использоваться вместо того? Хотя тут ещё с пространствами имён не понятно...

Comment: @Андрей: Ну, то же самое: если у кого-то «в руках» тип `EntitySet<T>`, будет использоваться новый. А если всего лишь `IEnumerable<T>` — старый.